# Is it possible to put Hi DPI images like 2x, 3x and 4x in a SVG image pattern?

Tags: html, css, svg

Is there a way to support 2x, 3x and 4x images in SVG pattern?

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#Avatar {
 opacity: 1;
 fill: url(#Avatar_A0);
}
.Avatar {
 position: absolute;
 overflow: visible;
 width: 38px;
 height: 38px;
 left: 10px;
 top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<title>Support HiDPI Images</title>

</head>
 
<svg class="Avatar">
    <pattern id="Avatar_A0" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/?d=identicon" xlink:href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/?d=identicon"></image>
    </pattern>
    <rect id="Avatar" rx="19" ry="19" x="0" y="0" width="38" height="38">
    </rect>
</svg>
</html>
```

I want to avoid JavaScript and either set SVG attributes if available or set CSS.

Is there is anything like:

```
<pattern id="Avatar_A0" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
    <image href="icon.png 1x, icon@2x.png 2x, icon@3x.png 3x" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
</pattern>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a HTML `<img>` tag wrapped in a `<foreignObject>` tag:

```
<pattern id="Avatar_A0" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
    <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
        <img srcset="icon.png 1x, icon@2x.png 2x, icon@3x.png 3x"
             x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
    </foreignObject>
</pattern>
```