# SVG foreignObject in an SVG pattern doesn't work

Tags: html, svg

I can't seem to get a foreignObject to work from within an SVG pattern. I can get it to work on its own, but not in a pattern. I've had a quick look around:

- its listed as a valid content element for a pattern in [SVG 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#Patterns) and [SVG 2.0](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/pservers.html#Patterns)
- [Its used in this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063465/is-it-possible-to-put-hi-dpi-images-like-2x-3x-and-4x-in-a-svg-image-pattern/54063828#54063828)
- [Something about not allowing foreignObject and svg:use, but I don't know if its relevant](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/511)

so I'm at a loss really what I'm doing wrong. I've added a contrived snippet to reproduce below, but I'm specifically interested in arbitrary html in a foreignObject, in a pattern.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>HTML inside SVG</title>
  <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="500" height="300" style="border:1px red solid" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        
        <!-- doesn't work -->
        <pattern id=tex width=100 height=100>
          <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
            <img xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/258/200/200.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
           </foreignObject>
        </pattern> 
        

        <pattern id=tex2 width=100 height=100>
          <circle fill=blue cx=50 cy=50 r=50 width=100 height=100></circle>
        </pattern>   
        
        <!-- foreignObject on its own works -->
        <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100">
             <img xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/258/200/200.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />  
        </foreignObject>  

        <!-- pattern with foreignObject doesn't work-->
        <rect fill="url(#tex)" stroke="black" x=0 y=100 width="100" height="100"/>
        <!-- basic pattern works-->
        <rect fill="url(#tex2)" stroke="black" x=0 y=200 width="100" height="100"/>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Instead of using a foreign object inside a pattern you can use a `<image>` element like so: `<pattern id="tex" width=".5" height=".5"> <image xlink:href="https://i.picsum.photos/id/258/200/200.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" /> </pattern> `

Comment: the example is contrived for the purpose of a simple reproduction - For real, I'm getting html element with other things in it. The idea was to use embed the arbitrary html into the pattern and then use multiple primitives (using the pattern) with their own matrix transforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m afraid it looks like browsers don’t support this, even though the spec says it’s valid.

- https://bugzilla-dev.allizom.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1348768
- https://bugzilla-dev.allizom.org/show_bug.cgi?id=486240
- Here’s another demo of the issue from 2014 `codepen.io/yoksel/details/BidHq` (SO won’t let me post the link without accompanying code, but the code is irrelevant in this case)

Comment: dam - I guess that's that then. Thanks.